# Vuetify expansion panel with v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working with the Vuetify expansion panel and i am using an array `Headers` to loop over and get the headers and another array named `elements` to loop over and get the desired text. How can i make it so that the text from `elements` array show up only under their respective panel. So basically for the panel, Animals, only Cat an Dog show up etc.

Here is a link to the sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/oNXwYXz)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Animals'
        },
        {
          text: 'Food'
        },
        {
          text: 'Colors'
        }
      ],
      elements: [{
          text: 'Cat',
          panel: 'Animals'
        },
        {
          text: 'Dog',
          panel: 'Animals'
        },
        {
          text: 'Chocolates',
          panel: 'Food'
        },
        {
          text: 'Pizza',
          panel: 'Food'
        },
        {
          text: 'Red',
          panel: 'Colors'
        },
        {
          text: 'Yellow',
          panel: 'Colors'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(header,i) in headers" :key="i">
        <template v-slot:header>
          <div>{{header.text}}</div>
        </template>
        <template v-for="element in elements" :key="element">
          <v-card v-if="element.panel == 'Animals'">
          <v-card-text >
            {{element.text}}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
        </template>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

So basically the Animals Content should contain Dog and Cat, Food should contain Chocolate and Pizza and Colors should contain Red and yellow. Thank You :)

Comment: `<v-card v-if="element.panel == header.text">`

Comment: Thank you. if you add this below, i'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: there's other solutions, that would require changing the format of the data, is that a possibility?

Comment: If you want to create a codepen to sample it, sure. go ahead. All ideas are welcomed :)

Comment: I've added it to the answer - I don't "codepen" in general :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution, that doesn't require changing the data format, rather than hard code the v-if as in

```
<v-card v-if="element.panel == 'Animals'">
```

You want to check if the element panel belongs to the current header

```
<v-card v-if="element.panel == header.text">
```

You can also change the data format (not tested, could be errors below)

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            headers: [{
                    text: 'Animals',
                    elements: [{
                            text: 'Cat'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Dog'
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    text: 'Food',
                    elements: [{
                            text: 'Chocolates'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Pizza'
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    text: 'Colors',
                    elements: [{
                            text: 'Red'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Yellow'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

and then the markup would be

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(header,i) in headers" :key="i">
        <template v-slot:header>
          <div>{{header.text}}</div>
        </template>
        <v-card v-for="element in header.elements" :key="element">
          <v-card-text >
            {{element.text}}
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a computed property that returns a function (although I like @JaromandaX' first idea better, it's simpler).

```js
computed: {
  elementsByPanel() {
    return (panel) => {
      return this.elements.filter(el => el.panel === panel);
  }
}
```

Use it like this

```html
    <template v-for="element in elementsByPanel(header.text)" >
      <v-card :key="element.text">
        <v-card-text >
          {{element.text}}
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </template>
```

This might be preferable if the filter criteria was more complex, as a computed property is more easily tested than an expression in the template.